# iOS: send heartbeat to the server while phone is locked and the app is on the background/suspended

Tags: ios, background, location, heartbeat, locked

I have the task.

- My iOS app must send heartbeat messages to the server once for every 10 minutes.
- iOS app must do this always when the app is not killed (i.e. terminated i.e. removed from task manager) **despite the screen is locked, the app in the background**.

I'm trying to do this using "background location". But if I use CLLocationUpdate in its' usual mode - I get my battery drained.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck, this is not possible on iOS. Yes you can use the location manager, but if I set a my desk for an hour your app will not get a location update.

Also it is misusing the background location mode and might get your app rejected.

An option can be to use silent push notification, you server will send a silent push to the device where the device will respond to it in the background.
Read more about 
[`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) and the [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194).